# Three verb term for joining in order to neutralize

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to recall a three word term used to describe joining an organization, committee etc. in order to neutralize or disrupt it. For example, by changing the scope, insisting on arbitrary standards that prevent moving forward, that sort of subterfuge.

The term is in the form   "a. b. c." where a, b, and c are verbs.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @user405662 No, not positive, memory is hazy. But I think it's along the lines of "Adapt. Improvise. Overcome".

Comment: _shake up_ by any chance? Though that doesn't fit the _verb-verb-verb_ template.

Comment: Is "subvert" the last one?

Comment: @GArthurBrown possibly.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this slogan on Anarcho-Punk record sleeves/patches/posters, but it is difficult to search for.

Comment: Sounds a bit like 'Adopt, Adapt, Improve', the [motto](https://www.agil8.com/blog/adopt-adapt-improve/) of the Round Table movement.

Comment: @GArthurBrown That might be an important clue. I've found "Delay, Distract, Defer" as a general sabotage technique, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Crush kill destroy!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's requesting a slogan rather than a phrasal unit. Essentially, a request for a specific quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints. I've found the phrase in question, and it has been fairly widely used. Any haziness as to the original question is on me.

> [Embrace, extend, and extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish), also known as "embrace, extend,
> and exterminate" is a phrase that the U.S. Department of Justice found
> that was used internally by Microsoft to describe its strategy for
> entering product categories involving widely used standards, extending
> those standards with proprietary capabilities, and then using those
> differences in order to strongly disadvantage its competitors.
>
> The strategy's three phases are:
>
> - Embrace: Development of software substantially compatible with a    competing product, or implementing a public standard.
> - Extend:    Addition and promotion of features not supported by the competing    product or part of the standard, creating
>   interoperability problems    for customers who try to use the "simple"
>   standard.
> - Extinguish: When    extensions become a de facto standard because of their dominant    market share, they marginalize competitors that do
>   not or cannot    support the new extensions.

Alliteration seems to be a common feature of phrases of this form.

Answer (score 1):

"Infiltrate, assassinate, destabilize"

From Captain America: Civil War.

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/7a5fdc55-d7d5-4df6-ad2b-f4184712c912

=====================

"Infiltrate | Assimilate | Destroy"

https://www.pastemagazine.com/noisetrade/music/wyndsrfr/infiltrate-assimilate-destroy

=====================

Infiltrate, subvert, control

https://www.jewishpolicycenter.org/2017/09/27/cybercrime-russian-tools-infiltrate-subvert-control/

========================

One of those? Something similar? I'll bet it starts with "infiltrate" at least.